# What is UI main fluid container in HTML?

Tags: java, html, playframework, coding-style

Not able to understand effects it creates in the HTML. Like what it means when written as

Comment: And I don't understand what `java` and `playframework` has to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fluid container is a Bootstrap class, it causes your div to span over the whole screen of the web application:

Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing your outermost .container to .container-fluid.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but a fluid container allows you to turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout. Meaning if the width of your screen/browser changes, the fluid container will fix the viewport to fit those changes.